# how to make sure other programmers don't put backdoors and callbacks in my site!

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, security, apache

How can I look for any client side call backs in javascript. I have people adding javascript code for me. how do I make sure they are not somehow sending confidential data or user info to their sites through client side POST, GET, AJAX or any client side methods!

How would I do the same thing for my server side code like to see my php programmer is not doing the same thing!??

I thought of having some firewall maybe apache log or something that would log or even block any outside contact over certain ports and log the ones that can't be blocked like port 80 and 8080, however I don't know how to get about this!
Same thing with the client side, if could browse the site and have my computer show any callbacks. I have the live http header extension for firefox but I was wondering if there is an easy way! 
and my whole concept is faulty as any smart programmer would make it so that it doesnt do this all the time so it might go unnoticed! I'm just wondering if their is a list of all the possible javascript and php functions that could be dangerous!
I would really appreciate an answer to any of these questions. Thank you so much!

Comment: You could hire trustworthy programmers and not allow users to input Javascript. Both are generally considered best practices.

Comment: If you don't trust them then why are you allowing them to put code on your site?

Comment: If you're hiring people to write code for you, you should trust them.  You're going to establish a bad employee relationship if you think that everyone out there is trying to ruin/hack your website.  Now, if someone DOES decide to be a baddie and stick malicious code on your site, you can take proper administrative action then.

Comment: You seem to have more of a social issue than a technical one. Learn to trust your partners and review each others code.

Comment: I agree with everyone else who's saying that if you can't trust your programmers not to misuse their access, you have bigger problems that can't be solved with technology. However, since you mentioned firewalling, I thought I'd offer a link to my website where I have an [IPTables tutorial](http://www.ellipsix.net/geninfo/firewall/index.html) that explains the process of setting up a reasonably secure firewall configuration. It's just a good idea to be familiar with this stuff if you are administering a Linux server.

Comment: Good security is just prudent planning, keeping honest people honest. People you THINK are honest often turn out to be dirty. Just recently my university caught 2 campus police officers (not just security guards, state paid police officers) copying student records and getting their credit card numbers.  Over $200K of charges were made before they were caught. If you cannot trust a police officer who can you trust :)

Answer (score 5):

1. Check every checkin/do code reviews.
2. If you can't trust your programmers, look for different programmers.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Firebug extension for Firefox, and enable the console. It will show you any ajax POST or GET requests.

Answer (score 2):

if you know some level of programming, do [CODE REVIEW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_review).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a direct answer, but related... As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325626/security-issue-of-extjs/3325730#3325730), you should check out the book [Ajax Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321491939).  I don't recall if it specifically deals with your direct concern of personnel trust, but it does deal with many concrete issues of security in this area and may give you some good ideas for things to watch for, or preventative measures to take.